# Has Chewbacca ever ripped anyone's arm off?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

From *A New Hope*:

> Chewbacca: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrgh!
>    C-3PO: He made a fair move. Screaming about it can't help you.
>    Han Solo: Let him have it. It's not wise to upset a Wookiee.
>    C-3PO: But sir, nobody worries about upsetting a droid.
>    Han Solo: **That's 'cause droids don't pull people's arms out of their sockets when they lose. Wookiees are known to do that.**
>    Chewbacca: Grrf.
>    C-3PO: I see your point, sir. I suggest a new strategy, R2: let the Wookiee win.

While Han was probably joking, it raises the question; was Han basing this on personal experience? Had he ever seen Chewbacca rip anyone's arms off?

[image: Chewbacca ripping out the arms of a stormtrooper]

Comment: I was going to say, if you play *Lego Star Wars* as the Chewbacca character, he rips pretty much everyone's arms off.

Comment: I love how happy he looks when he rips people's arms off.

Comment: It's interesting how people read Han's statement as the arms being torn completely off.  Threat of a mere shoulder dislocation would be enough of a deterrent for me to throw the game.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## In Legends: Yes

[Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca) says:

- [Ssoh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ssoh) (From [Star Wars: Chewbacca](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Chewbacca))

  > Ssoh became the only Trandoshan to live after a hand-to-hand battle with Chewbacca after the enraged Wookiee ripped his arms and his legs out of their sockets

  [image: Angry Chewie]
- An unfortunate droid
  [image]
  (From [The Art of Star Wars Galaxy: Volume Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars_Galaxy:_Volume_Two))

  > Chewbacca angrily pulls a droid's arm out of its socket over a holoboard game.

And then, of course, in the Lego Games...

[image]

## But in canon

The [canon section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca/Canon) only makes reference to the excerpt from *A New Hope* cited in the question.  Hence, it's reasonable to assume that Chewbacca probably *has* pulled out someone's arms before in canon, it's just we haven't seen it!

---

## On a side note...

The [Wookieepedia page on Wookiees](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wookiee) explains that:

> Wookiees also had the justified reputation of ripping the arms of
>   their enemies out of their sockets, which was known to occur in
>   instances of losing a game. That state of racial rage served as the
>   basis of the deal-slang expression **"wookinate", which referred to the
>   rendering harmless an enemy using excessive force—obviously referring
>   to the great physical strength that provided the essence of Wookiee
>   combat**

Comment: [It's only a flesh wound!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKhEw7nD9C4)

Comment: Wait, is the droid image from *Star Wars: Chewbacca* or from the art book?

Comment: @RogueJedi sorry for that confusion; I've reformatted it to make it more clear :D

Comment: I was **ahem** "acquiring" the comic to answer this, so I figured I may as well improve your answer with what I found

Comment: @JasonBaker Thanks. Also, thanks for clearing it up N_Soong.

Comment: @JasonBaker many thanks for that :D  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: He rips off 0-0-0's arms in a relatively recent comic.

Comment: For the record, I think **this answer should remain the accepted one**, due to its thoroughness and attention to detail, despite the fact that my answer cites new canon which makes the answer indisputably yes :-)

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, he has (sorta).

In the latest edition of the [Marvel Star Wars comics](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/52661/star_wars_2015_10) (considered a full part of the Star Wars canon) Chewie does indeed rip a droid's arm off. He then proceeds to use the ragged end to beat the unfortunate <s>former</s> owner to death.

You may wish to note that this is set *after* after ANH and that Han was actually not present at the time of the assault.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In [a deleted scene](https://youtu.be/mJLmdLRUPtE) from [*The Force Awakens*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_VII_The_Force_Awakens) (2015) the character [Unkar Plutt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unkar_Plutt) gets his arm ripped off by [Chewbacca](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca) after he confronts and threatens [Rey](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rey) in [Maz Kanata’s castle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maz_Kanata's_castle). Unkar harasses Chewbacca by poking him in the arm—right where he was wounded—and Chewbacca responds in kind by ripping Unkar’s arm off. This scene is supposedly a part of [the deleted scenes on the *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* 3D Blu-Ray](http://dorksideoftheforce.com/2016/10/18/watch-a-deleted-scene-from-the-force-awakens-chewbacca-vs-unkar-plutt/) that was released on November 15, 2016.

Just note that I’m not too clear on whether a deleted scene like this is considered “canon” but I guess that is hinged on whether Unkar Plutt shows up with both arms intact in a future film.

[image: Unkar Plutt pokes Chewbacca in his wounded arm.]

Currently active [YouTube video can be found here](https://youtu.be/mJLmdLRUPtE). It can also [be seen on Imgur right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC9oL.jpg).

Comment: It's just a flesh wound...

Comment: I wish they'd left that in.

Comment: Not canon, but still funny.

Answer (score 10):

The release of new canon necessitates a new answer to this question.

### Yes, in canon too.

In Alan Dean Foster's novelisation of *Star Wars: the Force Awakens*, Chewbacca rips off Unkar Plutt's arm:

> Grabbing the thrusting arm, a roaring Chewbacca twisted and ripped it off at the shoulder, throwing the dismembered limb clear across the room. Looking down at himself, Plutt let out a scream of agony

Although this didn't appear in the released film, [rumour has it](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/star-wars/38314/star-wars-the-force-awakens-did-chewbacca-have-a-major-scene-cut) that it *was* filmed in a scene which has since been deleted.

Comment: [Confirmed](http://www.cinemablend.com/m/new/Star-Wars-Force-Awakens-Almost-Featured-More-From-Two-Characters-111637.html)

Comment: Deleted scenes are not canon.

Comment: @Valorum I didn't say they were ... but novelisations are, right? I'm not sure why this answer merited a downvote.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I down voted for the reason above. The novelisations are only canon where they agree with the final cut of the movie. In this instance it disagrees with the movie. Unkar didn't turn up again in the film, nor did he get his arm ripped off.

Comment: @Valorum "The novelisations are only canon where they agree with the final cut of the movie" - really? From [here](https://twitter.com/DelReyStarWars/status/461579307341840384), it still seems to be unclear whether novelisations count as canon whenever they don't contradict the film or only when they directly parrot the film. Does that mean all answers which are based on novelisations **alone** are worth downvoting?

Comment: The new novelisations are fully canon where they agree with what happened on screen or elaborate on things that happened off screen. Elements that disagree with what happened on-screen are considered Legends. I downvoted because you've said that because it's in the novel, that it's canon. That's incorrect.

Comment: @Valorum Does the arm-ripping-off thing disagree with what happened on-screen? The newer (and undownvoted) answer from Jake Gould suggests that later films may confirm that this *did* happen off-screen, if Plutt shows up again with only one arm. If so, then surely this is a case where the novelisation is "elaborat[ing] on things that happened off screen".

Comment: @Randal'Thor - In the novel the arm-ripping culminated with a droid seeing the severed arm, then noticing Chewbacca and BB-8. In the film the sequence of events immediately leading up to the First Order being told about his presence was different, hence the film is canon and the novel is not.

Comment: @Valorum I have rewatched the movie, and can confirm it's definitely possible chewie ripped somebody's arm off, specifically between the first test/firing of Starkiller base (where everybody runs out to see) and when Maz leads Han and co. to the lightsaber.

Comment: It's stated earlier in the movie when they first meet Maz that chewie is working on the ship, I assume he runs outside to look at the pretty explosions in the sky and then follows han and co. back inside. At any point from there on until they leave the castle again, he could have ripped the arm off. I don't know exactly when the novel says that happened however.