# Which named characters have gotten their limbs torn by Wookiees?

Tags: star-wars

I have been a fan of Star Wars for almost half my life now and I don't recall ever witnessing any proof of the Wookiees' reputation. How has this managed to go unnoticed? Not even a single named Vong?

Canon and Legends both accepted.

Comment: Not all Wookiees just Chewie listed here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103796/22917

Comment: @N_Soong but if it's just Chewie, Han would have said "Chewie" instead of "Wookie". Quite clearly Han is making a reference to species.

Comment: exactly, which is why I didn't say this was a dupe 

Comment: however, we'll see what comes out of [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114735/22917) whether he may have been making an unfounded generalisation

Comment: @N_Soong In Legends, Han was a former stormtrooper who broke Chewie out of slavery. In canon, Han was raised by Wookies. I would guess this is likely borne out of observation in routine life, or learnt from nights of Wookie storytelling.

Answer (score 2):

## Disney Canon:

- **Unkar Plutt** (Chewie) - *"The Force Awakens" novelization by Foster (but not in theater film release)*.

  > Grabbing the thrusting arm, a roaring Chewbacca twisted and ripped it off at the shoulder, throwing the dismembered limb clear across the room. Looking down at himself, Plutt let out a scream of agony

## EU/Legends:

- Trandoshan named **Ssoh** (Chewie).

  There were a couple of unnamed droids but they don't count as per the question's title.

  *Hat/tip: [this awesome answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103796/976)*
- **Larrad Shrike** (Dewlanna). Details [in my answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114756/976).

  Wasn't quite ripped off, just broken, but matters because that was the first - and most important - attempt in EU to retcon that famous line from ANH.